# How to implement a side menu that swipes from the left?

Tags: menu, dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter and just finished the get started tutorial. I would like to create a side menu, which will appear from the left side when you swipe (like Gmail on Android).

Unfortunately, I can't find such a layout on the documentation and the example from the flutter gallery is a bit messy.

Could someone please explain me how to implement such a Widget?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kg6wo50XOkg, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery

Comment: Man you rock ! Thanks for the youtube channel.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is an example for a simple Drawer (I just adapted the default project setup from `flutter create`):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('TestProject'),
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget> [
            new DrawerHeader(child: new Text('Header'),),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text('First Menu Item'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text('Second Menu Item'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            new Divider(),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text('About'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text(
          'Center',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Drawer-class.html) are a good place to start ;)

Btw: including a drawer in your scaffold also takes care of the menu button and the left swipe gesture for you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Stocks example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/stocks/lib/stock_home.dart#L116) has a somewhat less complicated use of [`Drawer`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Drawer-class.html).

Comment: pls avoid dead links 

Answer (score 0):

In Scaffold just specify the `drawer: Drawer()`

Example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(   // this will set the drawer
        child: MyWidget // render your drawer Widget here
      ),
      ... // props hidden
    );
  }
}
```