# How to remove the hamburger button from a flutter drawer?

Tags: flutter

I've [seem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720930/flutter-side-menu) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953410/flutter-drawer-widget-change-scaffold-body-content) on how to set up a drawer in Flutter (`return new Scaffold(drawer: new Drawer( ... )` or `return new Scaffold(endDrawer: new Drawer( ... )`).

How can I remove the hamburger button at the top (so that you can only get the drawer through sliding from the side (or through a custom button in the app - that I know how to do))?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just set the `leading` property in your `AppBar` to an empty `Container`

```
appBar: new AppBar(
          leading: new Container(),
    ....
```

And in order to remove `endDrawer` (for RtL). It is placed where the `action` property is, so also just add an empty `Container` as a single `child` of the `action` property

```
appBar: new AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          new Container(),
        ],
.....
```

Comment: That removes the left-hand button. How should I remove the right-hand button?

Comment: Override the action property, check the answer.

Comment: After setting new Container() to leading it still occupies some space (empty box). As the result, there will be a gap before 'title'. To remove it, see the answer below.

Answer (score 52):

In **AppBar** you need to do the following to hide default rendering hamburger icon

```
AppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // this will hide Drawer hamburger icon
  actions: <Widget>[Container()],   // this will hide endDrawer hamburger icon
  ... // other props
),
```

and In **SilverAppBar** do the following to hide default rendering hamburger icon

```
SliverAppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // this will hide Drawer hamburger icon
  actions: <Widget>[Container()],   // this will hide endDrawer hamburger icon
  ... // other props
}
```

I hope this will help...

Comment: There is a typo in SliverAppBar. It is sliver, not silver

Answer (score 14):

Use the https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar/automaticallyImplyLeading.html property on the AppBar

Answer (score 7):

For the normal drawer you should set https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar/automaticallyImplyLeading.html to false.

For the end drawer you should do the following:

```
actions: [Container()]
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting `automaticallyImplyLeading` to false worked for me on a `SliverAppBar`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have stacked the `AppBar()` widget over the top of the `SliverAppBar()` you need to do `automaticallyImplyLeading: false` in `SliverAppBar()` widget only.

This will remove the Hamburger icon from the `AppBar`.

By the way, why it is happening as such? Could someone tell me?

Am not getting it....

Answer (score 1):

*Simply add this to your* **Appbar `automaticallyImplyLeading: false,`**