# How do I hide/remove the EndDrawer hamburger icon from my AppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know if you set automaticallyImplyLeading: false that it will remove the regular Drawer hamburger icon, but how would I do this for an EndDrawer?

I already tried setting automaticallyImplyLeading: false and nothing happened, any other ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034480/how-to-remove-the-hamburger-button-from-a-flutter-drawer